# .bin File is downloading in flutter webview instead a pdf file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview, android-webview

I am downloading a pdf file in webview(flutter_inappwebview),but after downloading i see .bin extension file,The pdf downloading page is locked behind login,so i tried including headers like cookies,userAgents
please solve the my question ?

Comment: check in the url I think you are getting wrong mime type

Comment: i am trying to mime type  ,i am getting null

Comment: Including the cookies should work, as I am currently working on a project that requires pdf download behind the login and it works(we are using flutter_inappwebview - this package has its own Cookie Manager). Check your login/authorization listeners on your web application or include JWT into your web app.

Answer (score 1):

Govt Website Restrict Download of  pdf ,So i finally generated own pdf

Comment: You should add some more detailed explanation of how this worked and why it solved the problem you described at the top of the page.